# Add class to ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 SELECT tag when rendered [Meteor JS + Blaze]

Tags: css, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

Meteor 1.6.1.1 is the latest version of my project. I am using package ***ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3*** instead of ***accounts-ui***. I have added a custom field as `<select>` in the code.

**What I get on Screen is as below.**

[image]

When I saw the HTML code, it is not adding `class="form-control"` to `select` tag.

below is the code when I inspect element on UI using Chrome.

```
<li id="login-dropdown-list" class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Sign in / Join <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="select-dropdown">
            <label>State</label><br>
            <select id="login-state">
            </select>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 col-sm-12" id="login-buttons-password" type="button">
            Create
        </button>
        <button id="back-to-login-link" class="btn btn-default col-xs-12 col-sm-12">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</li>
```

All I want is to add `class="form-control"` to the `select` tag dynamically when component loads on screen and it must look like below;

[image]

I have tried below code, but it is not working;

```
Template.HomePage.onRendered(function () {
    document.getElementById('login-state').classList.add('form-control');
});
```

Comment: I think you have to warp it with `form-group` https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried one way to achieve this is by using Template event as below,

```
Template.HomePage.events({
    'click #login-dropdown-list': function(event){
        //document.getElementById('login-state').classList.add('form-control');
        $('#login-state').addClass('form-control');
    }
});
```

As you can see, the component gets loaded inside the `li` tag with `id="login-dropdown-list"`. I simply loaded the class on click event. Even the commented code works fine.

Is this a good solution? please let me know if there much better answer to this? If it works I will definitely accept and upvote the answer.